# Keep the first line from a block of related lines

Tags: python, bash

I have a file with lines like this:

```
r1  300  #keep this one
r1  200
r1  100
r1  100
r2  100  # "
r2  200
r3  200  # "
r3  100
r3  300
```

I only need to keep the first line of each "block" (r1,r2,r3,etc)

desired output:

```
r1  300
r2  100
r3  200
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Could you not do `awk '!a[$1]++'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    curr = None
    for line in infile:
        if line == curr:
            continue
        print(line)
        curr = line
```

Or with bash:

```
cat path/to/file | uniq
```

Or with itertools:

```
import itertools

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line,_stuff in itertools.groupby(infile):
        print(line)
```

Comment: Nice python solutions, although as well as being a useless use of `cat`, the one using `uniq` doesn't work (every line is printed).

Comment: In fact, I don't see how the first python one is detecting any change in the first word on the line? It looks like it's comparing the whole line.

Answer (score 6):

You can keep track of changes to the first column and only print when it is different:

```
awk '$1 != last; {last = $1}' file
```

The part before the semicolon has an implicit `{print}` action, so the row will be printed if the first column is not equal to the value of `last` (edited, thanks). The block after the semicolon is run unconditionally and assigns the value of the first column to the variable `last`.

Slightly safer is to treat the first line separately (as I had done originally) and add an extra condition:

```
awk '!last || $1 != last; {last = $1}' file
```

This handles the case when the first column on the first line contains the number `0`, which would be evaluated as equal to `last` before it has been assigned a value.

If the contents of the first column are never repeated, you could make the script much simpler, as pointed out in the comments (thanks):

```
awk '!seen[$1]++' file
```

This only prints lines whose first column has not yet been seen, as `seen[$1]` evaluates to false. The `++` means that on subsequent lines with the same value of `$1`, `seen[$1]` has been incremented so evaluates to true.

Comment: Can be simpler: `awk '!seen[$1]++'`

Comment: you don't need `!last ||` if `last` doesn't exist it isn't going to match `$1`.Could just be `awk '$1!=x&&x=$1'`

Comment: For my previous comment, the exception is if $1 is 0, which doesn't look likely from OPs data

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Jidder, I've used some of them in my answer.

Comment: @TomFenech glad to help! also i thought i would point out that it will only fail if the first field is 0 AND it is the first line.